# How to found in Java common part of many Maps?

Tags: java, collections, maps, intersection

I have many maps like `Map(String, Object)`.

```
map1
map2
....
mapN
```

I need to receive map that contains only these key-value pairs where first parameter is equal in all maps.
Could it be done by using `retainAll` method?

Comment: What is *"first parameter"*? The key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it using `retainAll`

```
map1.keySet().retainAll(map2.keySet());
map1.keySet().retainAll(map3.keySet()); //etc
```

At last `map1` will be intersection of all keys in your all maps so these keys are common now you can retrieve value easily

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You get one of the Sets and use `retainAll` with all of the others, the remainder elements are common to all of the sets.

The missing step is getting all the keys of the maps as a `Set`, which is done by `Map.keySet()`

Note that the `retainAll` is marked as optional, so maybe the implementation of the `Set` returned by `Map.keySet` does not implement it. In that case, create a new Set instance that does support it passing the original set as parameter.